# Looping won't stop when reading user input

Tags: c, logic

This code cannot stop looping even when I enter n or N.

What is causing this?

```
    char next = "";

    printf("Do u want continue\n");
    scanf("%c", &next);
    getchar();
    do
    {
        if (next=='y' ||next=='Y')
        {
            selection();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("invalid Please Enter again");
            scanf("%c", &next);
        }
    } while (next !='n'|| next!='N')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional `(next !='n'|| next!='N')` is always true.

If `next` is `'n'` then `next!='N'` is true making the whole expression true.  Similarly, if `next` is `'N'` then `next!='n'` is true again making the whole expression true.

What you want here is to use a logical AND `&&`:

```
} while (next !='n' && next!='N')
```

Comment: thank man but I m still facing another problem. when I enter n it will loop to the else statement 1st  before close. i don't have any idea for this. the program will read step by step.so how can i solve it?

Comment: @WangLiangwei You need to add an additional check to see if the result is `'n'` or `'N'` and only prompt again if it's not.

Comment: @WangLiangwei Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Your while conditional will always evaluate to true. The input character will always be either NOT 'N' or NOT 'n'. Because it's only a single character, so it will always not be one of the two. You need you need to instead ensure that it's NEITHER of them. This is a logical AND check, rather than and OR check. So, instead, change that conditional to an AND, a.k.a `next !== 'n' && next !== 'N'`, or, if you find using OR makes more sense, the following conditional is equivalent to the AND statement, through use of Boolean logic transformations `!(next == 'n' || next == 'N')`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Besides dbush's answer which is correct:

- `char next = "";` is wrong, it should be `char next;`
- Don't use `scanf` but use only `getchar`, `scanf` is full of pitfalls.

Replace this:

```
char next;
...
scanf("%c", &next);
getchar();
```

with this:

```
int next;
...
next = getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (next !='n' || next!='N') is always true.
```

You can simply change it like this:

```
while (next !='n')
```

Then you input `n`, it stopped.